# Degree of field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(i,i\sqrt2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have a field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(i,i\sqrt2)$ that I want to find the degree of. Usually I find it easiest to find the minimal polynomial, but I can't start by saying $x=i,i\sqrt2$ now.

How can I find the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\i}{\mathfrak{i}}$
The first thing you want to do is to show that $\i \notin \Q(\i\sqrt{2})$. After you do this, you can break it up into a tower of simple extensions to find the degree:

$$
\left[\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2}):\Q\right] = 
\left[\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2}):\Q(\i\sqrt2)\right]
\left[\Q(\i\sqrt{2}):\Q\right] = 
(2)(2) = 4
$$

The general theorem that lets you do this looks something like

> Given a tower of field extensions $K \subset E \subset F$, we have $[F:K]=[F:E][E:K]$.

We need to show that $\i \notin \Q(\i\sqrt{2})$ so we know $\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2})\neq\Q(\i\sqrt2)$ (i.e. so we know that $\left[\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2}):\Q(\i\sqrt2)\right]\neq 1$). For the sake of contradiction if $\i \in \Q(\i\sqrt{2})$, we could write $\i = a + b\i\sqrt{2}$ for some $a,b \in \Q$ (this is because we can think of $\Q(\i\sqrt{2})$ as a vector space over $\Q$ with basis $\{1,\i\sqrt{2}\}$). Squaring both sides of this equation, we can reach a contradiction.

Now calculating $\left[\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2}):\Q(\i\sqrt2)\right]$ comes down to recalling that we can write $\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2})$ as $(\Q(\i))(\i\sqrt{2})$. Then if we give $(\Q(\i))$ the name $F$, and note that $2\in F$ and $\sqrt{2}\notin F$, we are really just calculating $[F:F(\sqrt{2})]$ (which is much less intimidating).

---

If you still want to talk about minimal polynomials, you can talk about the minimal polynomial of each of the intermediate extensions. For the extension $\Q \subset \Q(\i\sqrt{2})$ the minimal polynomial is $x^2+2$. For the extension $\Q(\i\sqrt2) \subset \Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2})$ the minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$ (since we are just adjoinging $\i$). Now if you wanted to characterize the full extension, you could say that $\Q(\i,\i\sqrt{2})$ is the splitting field over $\Q$ of the polynomial $(x^2+2)(x^2+1) = x^4 + 3x^2 +2$.

Comment: I have some questions: 1. How do you 'show' i∉Q(i2√)? 
2.How do you get [Q(i,i2√):Q(i2√)] = 2?

Comment: @clueless Once you have the answer to 1., which was just added as a final paragraph to the answer above, the answer to 2. is that the two fields are not equal (that was what 1. was about), so the degree is not $1$, but the extension is generated by the second-degree polynomial equation $x^2 + 1 = 0$, so the degree is at most $2$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(i,i\sqrt2)=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt2)$ and consider the tower $$\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)(i)$$ and use the tower law. In particluar $\sqrt2$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ while $i$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. This is because $i$ has degree at most $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and has degree at least $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ since $i\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Hence the degree of the required extension is $2\times 2=4$. 
Alternatively show that $$\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt2)=\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt2)$$ and compute the degree of the minimal polynomial of $i+\sqrt2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That last part, Q(i,2√)=Q(i+2√), is this a general rule? (i.e. that Q(a,b) = Q(a+b))

Comment: @clueless, although it's not a general rule, it is very often true. See the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: Was reading the wikipage, but i'm abit confused. Would the same apply if i were to find the polynomial for $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt 2)$ , or $\mathbb{Q}(i+i\sqrt 2)$  ?

Comment: Plus one for pointing out that $\{\sqrt2,i\}$ is a more satisfactory generating set for the field than $\{i,i\sqrt2\,\}$, in that it’s almost obvious now that the big field is of degree four over the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant but completely elementar solution is to prove that
$$
F=\{a+b\cdot i+c\cdot \sqrt{2}+d\cdot i\sqrt{2}|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Q\}
$$
(clearly a four dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$) is actually a field. 
This amounts essentially to prove that the moltiplicative inverses of elements of $F$ are still in $F$. In that case $F$ cannot be anything else than $\mathbb{Q}(i,i\sqrt2)$

Comment: If you go this way, then you also have to prove that $\{1, i, \sqrt2, i\sqrt2\}$ indeed is a _basis_ of the vector space, i.e. that the four elements are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$..

Comment: I think that this is a little bit different issue. I didn't say that my suggestion is  elementary in all respects. In fact, it only avoids the theorem about the composition of the degree.

Comment: I think it is the _exact_ same issue. Your solution only proves that the degree is at most four. You need to show what I said in order to prove that the degree is more than $3$.

Comment: Well, I think instead that this is actually the trivial issue; the calculation of the inverses is little more complicated. However these opinions are ininfluent.